# db2 : what is the best way to insert 2 variable on the same row

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I would like to create a function returning a table with 1 row only filled with 2 values pre-calculated.

Below my example to clarify what I mean

```
  create function()
  returns table(a integer,b integer)
  language sql
  begin
   declare c integer;
   declare d integer;
   set c=10;
   set d=20;
   -- how to return here c and d on the same row
   -- of a return table?
  end@
```

What is the best way to achieve that?
Should I create a temp table and insert those 2 values or is there a special statement or special use of `SELECT` to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's the *best way*, as you did not specify the criteria for being *the best*, but you can use the VALUES statement, like so:

```
create function()
returns table(a integer,b integer)
language sql
begin
 return values (10, 20);
end@
```

or, if you really need variables:

```
create function()
returns table(a integer,b integer)
language sql
begin
 declare c integer;
 declare d integer;
 set c=10;
 set d=20;
 return values (c, d);
end@
```